# Keras gradient wrt input for multiple output dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a keras model with a two-dimensional output (binary classification).

```
model.output # <tf.Tensor 'dense_1_3/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>
```

and

```
model.input # <tf.Tensor 'bidirectional_1_input:0' shape=(?, ?, 200) dtype=float32>
```

I evaluated three different gradients for some example input of shape (1,50,200)

```
gradients0 = K.gradients(model.output[:,0] model.inputs)
gradients1 = K.gradients(model.output[:,1], model.inputs)
gradients2 = K.gradients(model.output, model.inputs)
```

I thought, the first two expressions yield the gradient for the single output neurons and the last one yields a tensor containing the first two expressions.
To my surprise, all three gradients have a shape of `(1,50,200)`. In my opinion, gradients2 needs to be of shape `(2,50,200)` since `model.output` is two dimensional. What is keras computing in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras.backend.gradients() expects the output to be a scalar function, not a multi-dimensional one. I've found with a small example that K.gradients() performs identically that tf.gradients(). This way (as seen here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients), your *gradients2* is returning *a list of Tensor of length len(xs) where each tensor is the sum(dy/dx) for y in ys*, which explains why the first shape dimension is 1 and not 2.

This link can help you: [Tensorflow gradient with respect to matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878053/tensorflow-gradient-with-respect-to-matrix)