# Finding gradients in tensorflow without sum

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

Context: I am solving a PDE using CNN. And I need gradient of P w.r.t X.

P=[p1  p2 ; p3  p4 ],
X= [x1  x2;  x3  x4]

I need gradient of P w.r.t X. But Tensorflow gives me the sum of all the partials.

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post in latex format. So here's the same question I could post on Math.Stachexchange. Please click on this link for better clarity:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408736/finding-gradients-in-tensorflow-without-sum

What do I need to do to get the gradients as I need? I'd really appreciate your help. Searching for similar questions here didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the Jacobian matrix. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/compute_gradient and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48880275/3712254.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need the Jacobian. If you click on that link, you'll see it. I actually need  (partial p_i)/(partial x_i).

Comment: Can't you take the diagonal of the Jacobian, then reshape it from (16) to (4, 4)?

Comment: That's a good idea. In my case, P is 2x2, X is 2x2. So doing  Z=Jacobian(P,X) in tensorflow returns a [2,2,2,2] tensor, that has (partial p_i)/(partial x_j). So doing diagonal operation now doesn't quite help. I need to extract the needed (partial p_i)/(partial x_i), by means of slicing Z, which is getting super-slow, because this process has to be done many times during the training. If you have a better way, I'd really appreciate!!

Comment: That actually shouldn’t be too slow because you do the slice once at graph construction and not continuously at runtime - have you ran it and found it to be slow?

Comment: Yea, you are right. I observed that the first evaluation takes long. After that, it's not bad. I have a follow-up question though.     What I actually need are the sums of all  partials (partial p_i)/(partial x_i) . Now, if I start with  **sum=0**. And keep doing **sum=sum+partial** inside the for-loop, will that create a new sum-increment Op for each loop?

Comment: Yep, `sum`, at the end of that for loop, will be the addition of all of the partials because if `sum` and `partial` are tensors, then `+` should resolve to a `tf.add` operation. Alternatively, see if you can use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum.

Comment: 1) Ok, after the for-loop ends, I understand that the `sum` will have the sums of all my required partials. What I meant is: does the graph create a new Op each time the `sum=sum+partial` line is executed in the for-loop. And will it simply fill up my memory?

Comment: 2) Reg the `reduce_sum`, I am sceptical if I can use it. Because I don't need the entire sum or neither the sum reduced along certain axis. If J is my Jacobian, what I need is J[0,0,0,0]+J[0,1,0,1] +J[1,0,1,0]+J[1,1,1,1]. So perhaps `reduce_sum` is not useful for such selective-summing.

Comment: 1) It will create separate ops but that might not fill up your memory. What is your for-loop over? Feel free to paste some code here.

Comment: <!-- language: python -->
`sum=0
for i in np.arange(2):
    for j in np.arange(2):
        d1=tf.gradients(P[i,j], X)[0]  #outputs a [2,2]  tensor
        d2=tf.gradients(d1[i,j], X)[0] #finds the second derivative #also a [2,2] tensor
        sum.append(tf.slice(d2,[i,j],[1,1]))
#Finally sum contains all second derivatives  (\partial^2 p_i)/(\partial (x_i)^2 ) `

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure how to format the pasted code. (Here it is with proper indents: http://txt.do/1k2ch).      So in the code, I am actually computing the laplacian of P w.r.t X. So basically I am creating a list *sum*  of only the needed partials (\partial^2 p_i)/(\partial (x_i)^2.  I will finally sum them later when needed. Hope it is clear what I'm evaluating.