# TensorFlow gradient of matrix wrt a matrix is not making sense

Tags: tensorflow, autograd, tensorflow-gradient

Let's say i have two matrix tf_t (shape : 5x3 ) and tf_b ( shape : 3x3).
y_tf =  tf.matmul(tf_t, tf_b) and then I've computed dy/dt using tf.gradient api

```
import tensorflow as tf

mat = [[0.8363, 0.4719, 0.9783],
        [0.3379, 0.6548, 0.3835],
        [0.7846, 0.9173, 0.2393],
        [0.5418, 0.3875, 0.4276],
        [0.0948, 0.2637, 0.8039]]

another_mat = [[ 0.43842274 ,-0.53439844, -0.07710262],
               [ 1.5658046,  -0.1012345 , -0.2744976 ],
               [ 1.4204658 ,  1.2609464,  -0.43640924]]

tf_t = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(mat))
tf_b = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(another_mat))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  tape.watch(tf_t)
  y_tf = tf.matmul(tf_t, tf_b)
  y_t0 = y_tf[0,0]

# dy = 2x * dx
dy_dx = tape.gradient(y_tf, tf_t)
print(dy_dx)
```

I am getting below matrix as dy/dx

```
tf.Tensor(
[[-0.17307831  1.1900724   2.245003  ]
 [-0.17307831  1.1900724   2.245003  ]
 [-0.17307831  1.1900724   2.245003  ]
 [-0.17307831  1.1900724   2.245003  ]
 [-0.17307831  1.1900724   2.245003  ]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=float32)
```

The above matrix does not look right.
because for the element y_tf[0,0]

> Note :  y_tf[0,0] = tf_t[0,0]*tf_b[0,0] + tf_t[0,1]*tf_b[1,0] +
> tf_t[0,2]*tf_b[2,0]

if I perform

```
tape.gradient(y_t0, tf_t)
```

I get the matrix like this

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.43842274 1.5658046  1.4204658 ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.        ]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=float32)
```

The 1st row above is 1st column of matrix `tf_b` which makes sense given how matrix multiplication works and  If I were, to sum up, those numbers it's going to be `3.424693` However,  the result I got as `dy_dx` it has it's first element `dy_dx[0,0]` as `-0.17307831` which is a summation of 1st row of `tf_b ( sum(tf_b[0,:])` !!

So can anyone please explain hows the gradient of `tf_y[0,0] wrt tf_x` is reduced to `-0.17307831`  and not `3.424693`?

The question could appear similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878053/tensorflow-gradient-with-respect-to-matrix) but the answer I'm looking for is not addressed there with a clear picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key notion to understand here is that [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) computes the gradients of the **sum** of the output(s) with respect to the input(s). That is `dy_dx` represents the scale by which the sum of all elements of `y_tf` changes as each element of `tf_t` changes.

So, if you take `tf_t[0, 0]`, that value is used to compute `y_tf[0, 0]`, `y_tf[0, 1]` and `y_tf[0, 2]`, in each case with coefficients `tf_b[0, 0]`, `tf_b[0, 1]` and `tf_b[0, 2]`. So, if I increased `tf_t[0, 0]` by one, the sum of `y_tf` would increase by `tf_b[0, 0] + tf_b[0, 1] + tf_b[0, 2]`, which is the value of `dy_dx[0, 0]`. Continuing with the same reasoning, each value `tf_t[i, j]` is in fact multiplied by all the values in `tf_b[j, :]`, so `dy_dx` is a repetition of the sum of the rows of `tf_b`.

When you compute the gradient of `y_t0` with respect to `tf_t`, then changes in `tf_t[0, 0]` would change the sum of the result by a factor of `tf_b[0, 0]`, so that is the value of the gradient in that case.